# What's about Meta Site's events purposes?

Tags: discussion, meta, events

What is the  purposes of performing events on Meta? I'm talking about events like Winterbash and April Fools.

Are there any badges or tags for Meta site events?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events

Comment: @Azik I got this message: The events tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it? :)

Comment: I see a tag : [tag:winterbash-2013]

Comment: Can you please define "event" here? Do you mean some events like Winterbash or April fool etc.?

Comment: @hims056 yes , absolutely right sir. How did you know it ? I think it is an "event" of specific month. Example "HAPPY NEW YEAR !!". Here is events in World of Warcraft game http://www.wowwiki.com/Event

Comment: I participated on both. See [this tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools). For me the real fun of enjoying events is in Meta.

Comment: @Azik,hims056,Aziz Shaikh,Martijn Pieters,Motot ... will you satisfy with my question edition ? And I also have a question "Why didn't you leave any comment that you want to know exactly ?". Anotherway , you can edit questions.

Comment: There are already 4 reopen votes. need one more, be patient.

Comment: @Azik pls flg my comment " Thank you " ! :) . happy happy..

Comment: Me too @Sha....

Comment: @Cataclysm just to let you know `@Sha Wiz Dow Ard,hims056` is notifying only me due to the `@Sha` in the beginning, everything after the space is ignored as far as the comment reply notification cares. So if you were under the impression it's notifying both of us, it's a wrong assumption. :) (such thing is not possible anyway)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd,hims056 LOL , I will suggest a new feature request for buying hats with rep :) . I am kidding. Happy for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one word: fun.

There's no real purpose and you won't have anything left when the event is over other than warm feeling in your heart and some cool stories to tell your grandchildren. (e.g. "how the April fool expert tricked me" or "how I got that super ubber secret hat")

Enjoy!

Comment: I saw message "...but be quick – the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!" After event was expired, will the hats will gone(loose , will not bind anymore) ?

Comment: @Cataclysm gone indeed, only way to "preserve" them is take screenshots.

Comment: Oh! I will shout "Pls give me back my hats.. woarrr (Feeling:crying)!".By the way , is right my comment format @..? pls check on my question.

Comment: @Cataclysm you can shout but it won't help. :) regarding comment format I fear not... you can notify only one user each time. You can write something like `@ShaWizDowArd [comment here...]` then after a minute edit it to be `@hims056 [comment here...]` then in case we're both logged in and view the inbox we'll both get notified.